# how to parse html with the tags still being intact

Tags: java, html, dom, html-parsing, sax

I am trying to parse an html for example like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <header>hello</header>
     <p>
       this is a text<br/>
     </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And i want to extract

```
<p>
  this is a text<br/>
</p>
```

I have tried Jsoup:

```
private String parseTicketReply(String content) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
    String replybody = "";

    // zimbra 
    if (doc.select("body").size() > 0) {
        replybody = doc.select("body").get(0).text();
    }

    return replybody;            
}
```

I dont get what i want. I get "this is a text".

I tried SAX perser, neko, etc.... none of them are giving me the right result. anyone knows how to do it in the proper way? Really struggling with it. thanks in advance...

Comment: `<br/>this is a text</br>` isn't valid HTML. `<br>` means line break. You can read up on it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: yeah it was a typo, edited it. the problem still remains. that was not the reason it did not work.

Comment: @lkthiander in that case, please 1) update your question 2) format the code you provide. :)

Comment: thanks @wei2912 already updated. please comment about the java code or suggest any library you know.

Comment: yeah gives me <header>
 hello
</header>
<p><br />this is a text<br /></p>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37258/discussion-between-wei2912-and-ikthiander)

Comment: @wei2912 my friend, a humble request, this is a post about java, the errors of html are not in focus, i am looking for a specific answer from a java user, thank you

Comment: @lkthiander Anyway, that should be easy with SAX, what the start of the `<body>` element just set a `boolean` to read all, and on the end of the `<body>` set the `boolean` again.

Comment: @lkthiander if invalid html is being used, that may cause issues with the parser. that is what i'm trying to get you to fix and while i understand that they are not directly related to this issue, it is required to prevent future issues from occurring. sorry if i have hindered any form of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`replybody = doc.select("body").get(0).text();`

to

`replybody = doc.select("body").get(0).html();`

You could use `doc.body()` instead of `doc.select("body")`

In http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document

> The parser will make every attempt to create a clean parse from the HTML you provide, regardless of whether the HTML is well-formed or not.

Comment: it gives me <header>
 hello
</header>
<p><br />this is a text<br /></p>

Comment: Well its getting better, just the wrong node. `text()` will not return html tags.

Comment: @lkthiander This behaviour is intended as you asked for everything in `<body>`. If you wish to extract all `<p>` elements, that'd be a different thing.

Comment: @wei2912 But `<header> hello </header>` is not in body

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento i believe the JSoup parser fixes HTML pages. Because `<header>` is meant to be placed in the `<body>`, it may be moved there.

Comment: @wei2912 well, I don't worked with it, but if it changes the original document, that would be difficult.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento neither do i, i'm just speculating.

Comment: @lkthiander and now that you changed the HTML document? What is your intention? Extract all <p></p> tags inner HTML or just the first? If it is I would suggest to move to SAX again. If is only this document, and you know the structure is always that, you just need to change the node you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can parse your html with a regex.

For instance, this one will get you every paragraph with its tags :

```
<p>[\w\W]*</p>
```

You can try this :

```
String html = "<html>\n<header>hello</header>\n<body>\n<p>\n<br/>this is a text<br/>\n</p>\n</body>\n</html>";

System.out.println(html);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<p>[\\w\\W]*</p>)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(html);
matcher.find();

System.out.println("\nResult below :");
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: i dont want every paragraph, i want a specific text containing html inside a specific tag. also using regex to parse html is discouraged. but thanks for your input

Comment: A nongreeedy version: `<p>[\w\W]*?</p>` You may need to escape the backslash. As lkhtiander says, using regex to parse html is discouraged. @lkhtiander there's no other way to differentiate which paragraph you want. You may want to consider using a `<div id="blahblahblah">` to differentiate. Also, *please* write valid HTML.